# Update com subconsulta e inner Join - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Tabelas**

*Contrato*
*id, contrato, credor_id, devedor_id, evento_id, campanha_id*

*Titulo*
*id, contrato_id, titulo, vencimento, valor*

A idéia é atualizar o campo `campanha_id`  dos contratos utilizando uma subconsulta e Inner Join

A questão é: Como atualizar o campo campanha_id de todos os contratos retornados na consulta ?

Construí um exemplo completo com parametros de consulta no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fe32b/1) para melhor visualização das tabelas.

**Consulta sem update:**

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.contrato,
       t.valor_total
FROM   contrato c
       INNER JOIN(SELECT contrato_id,
                         Sum(valor) valor_total
                  FROM   titulo t
                  GROUP  BY contrato_id) t
               ON t.contrato_id = c.id
WHERE  c.credor_id = 2
```

**Consulta que retorno erro de sintaxe**

```
UPDATE c
SET    c.campanha_id = 5
FROM   contrato AS c
       INNER JOIN (SELECT contrato_id,
                          Sum(valor) valor_total
                   FROM   titulo t
                   GROUP  BY contrato_id) t
               ON t.contrato_id = c.id
WHERE  c.credor_id = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

> A idéia é atualizar o campo campanha_id dos contratos utilizando uma
> subconsulta e Inner Join
>
> A questão é: Como atualizar o campo campanha_id de todos os contratos
> retornados na consulta ?

Ajuste a sua consulta, transformando-a em um `UPDATE` da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE contrato c
       INNER JOIN(SELECT contrato_id,
                         Sum(valor) valor_total
                  FROM   titulo t
                  GROUP  BY contrato_id) t
               ON t.contrato_id = c.id
   SET c.campanha_id = 5               
 WHERE c.credor_id = 2
```

Observe que a sintaxe correta do `SET` no comando `UPDATE` do *MySql* é apresentado após as junções `inner join`.

Realizei o teste do comando no *SqlFiddle* disponibilizado [nesse link de acesso ao teste no SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19878c/1)

Realizei ajuste no exemplo fornecido no SqlFiddle da pergunta para poder realizar o teste, pois no comando inicial do autor menciona o campo `campanha_id` como requisito da resposta, mas na estrutura fornecida, o campo estava ausente.

Após execução dos comandos de criação das tabelas, inserção de valores e execução do UPDATE, o resultado do comando seguinte:

```
Select * from contrato
```

Apresentou o
**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19878c/1/0)**:

| id | contrato | credor_id | devedor_id | evento_id | campanha_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 123456 | 1 | (null) |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 654321 | 2 | (null) |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 654387 | 3 | 5 |

Em resposta ao [SqlFiddle da pergunta](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fe32b/1), é necessário também adaptar a consulta *SQL*, transformando-a em um `UPDATE` conforme demonstrado neste outro exemplo [de transformação de Consulta em Update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4aebd/1).